# How to select a specific stm32 board to debug on VisualStudioCode

Tags: debugging, stm32, vscode-debugger, stm32h743

I'm debugging my nucleo-h743zi2 using visual studio code on Linux. I want to connect different boards while debugging just one of them. To do so, I wrote this launch.json file

```
{
    // Usare IntelliSense per informazioni sui possibili attributi.
    // Al passaggio del mouse vengono visualizzate le descrizioni degli attributi esistenti.
    // Per altre informazioni, visitare: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Cortex Debug",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "executable": "/home/vincenzo/myProject/stm32h7xx/stm32h7xx-Driver/build/i2cIT.elf",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "device": "STM32H743ZI2",
            "targetId": "003300283438511034313939",
            "configFiles": [
                "board/st_nucleo_h743zi.cfg"
            ],
        "svdFile": "/home/vincenzo/myProject/stm32h7xx/stm32h7xx-Driver/STM32H743.svd"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm wondering if is there a simple way to select a specific nucleo board. In the stm32IDE I selected the proper board through the Run Configurations... -> Debugger -> ST-Link S/N setting the needed serial number.
Here I tried targetID and serialNumber with no results.

Can anyone help me?

best regards,
Vincenzo

Comment: with gdb and gdbserver, it works fine to select a given MCU thourgh S/N number.

Comment: hat do you mean by "no results" ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean the targetID parameter does not work. If I change the serial I can't debug the specified board. So I can't reach the board I want to debug to.